# How can I add a url prefix to Django Admin?

Tags: django, url, admin, prefix

I would like to add a prefix to a Django Admin url. 
For Example:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('bar/admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

If I add a prefix to an app url it works however I can't get the admin site to load.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply change the base `urls.py` as follows:

```
ADMIN_URL_PREFIX = 'bar'

url(r'^{}/admin/'.format(ADMIN_URL_PREFIX), include(admin.site.urls)),
```

I'd recommend keeping `ADMIN_URL_PREFIX` in settings.

Comment: From the Django 2.2 documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#url)    url(): This function is an alias to django.urls.re_path(). It’s likely to be deprecated in a future release.

Comment: Gives this error: `Passing a 3-tuple to include() is not supported. Pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name, and provide the namespace argument to include() instead`